# mysql drop multiple table using where or is not like condition?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

anyone can suggest me the query to delete multiple tables from database.?? like.......

> Drop table is not like 'prefix%';

please suggest me the right query to do that ??

Comment: possible duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8393550/mysql-drop-tables-with-wildcard-using-only-sql-statement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do it with just a single MySQL command, however you can use MySQL to construct the statement for you:

In the MySQL shell or through PHPMyAdmin, use the following query

```
SELECT CONCAT( 'DROP TABLE ', GROUP_CONCAT(table_name) , ';' ) 
AS statement FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_name LIKE 'myprefix_%';
```

This will generate a DROP statement which you can than copy and execute to drop the tables.

EDIT: A disclaimer here - the statement generated above will drop all tables in all databases with that prefix. If you want to limit it to a specific database, modify the query to look like this and replace database_name with your own database_name:

```
SELECT CONCAT( 'DROP TABLE ', GROUP_CONCAT(table_name) , ';' ) 
AS statement FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_schema = 'database_name' AND table_name LIKE 'myprefix_%';
```